# Padding on JFrame in Windows 7

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I noticed that on a `JFrame`, there is always padding for the blue borders in Windows 7 (they're something like 30 horizontally and 10 vertically). What are the exact values of these paddings and do they change between different versions of Windows?

Comment: Short answer is, yes, they change for all platforms, in fact they may change between computers running the same OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @MadProgrammer mentioned in a comment, the values differ between different looks and feels.  However, you can easily acquire the exact values at runtime using [`Container#getInsets()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getInsets%28%29).

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("title");
frame.setVisible(true);
System.out.println(frame.getInsets());
```

It's worth mentioning that the insets will all be `0` until the frame has been made visible.